# The Alias directive will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias

Tags: apache-httpd, alias

Here's the original post on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/665231/the-alias-directive-will-probably-never-match-because-it-overlaps-an-earlier-ali#):

The first 15 lines of my httpd.conf file

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen *:80
Listen *:443

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin hostmaster@localhost
ServerName 192.168.1.200:80

Include conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
```

Notice that the first time an external file is inserted is at the Include conf.d/*.conf line. And, the first file included is awstats.conf since it is alphabetical.

The first lines of awstats.conf are:

```
Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/classes/"
Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/css/"
Alias /awstatsicons "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/icon/"
ScriptAlias /awstats/ "/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"
```

So, the first Alias & ScriptAlias encountered are essentially after 16 lines since apache starts loading conf files. Yet, I still get the error that "The Alias directive will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias".

How can it overlap since no other ALIAS directive has been included so far? What am I missing?

EDIT:

Running `systemctl status httpd` results in the error mentioned:

```
The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf at line 4 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf at line 5 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf at line 6 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
```

Comment: Do any of the *.conf files have `Include` lines?

Comment: if your original question on [sf] is likely to be closed (or even deleted), please give the *full* context in **this** question. if it not going to be closed, why do you cross-post?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick just httpd.conf has the Includes. All the other ones do not. Although I did not check in /conf.modules.d

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html#startup to get the actual config Apache is looking at. That will probably make it clear what is going on.

Comment: Why do you think you're getting the error on the lines in the awstats.conf file, and not some later included file?

Comment: @wurtel I have no idea, but the actual config should show why.

Comment: @derobert my comment was directed at the person asking the question (who also states that those lines are giving the error), otherwise I would have mentioned your name...

Comment: @wurtel Hi, please check my edit. It shows the status of httpd and the errors. I omitted the welcome.conf errors since I commented welcome.conf includes.

Comment: Well, the most obvious thing that could be wrong is that you've somehow got `Include conf.d/*.conf` in there twice. Are there any more include lines?

Comment: @derobert OMG!!!! FINALLY!!! It was not an Include, it was a Stupid IncludeOptional in the httpd.conf down the file. That's WHY I couldn't find it. Stupid IncludeOptional !!! Thanks and please answer so I can accept

Comment: @fizzydrink Glad to hear its been solved. I added an answer—please feel free to edit in any details I left out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your grep results showing no other conflicting Aliases, the most likely explanation is that somehow you've got the file included twice. Look for any additional `Include` or `IncludeOptional` directives. (Especially this might occur on a 2.2→2.4 upgrade, as `IncludeOptional` is new.)

The other troubleshooting tip to deal with similar problems is that [mod_info can be made to dump the config on startup](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html#startup) which should show the full config.